# Why is a non UI thread able to modify UI control in WinForm & TPL?

Tags: .net, winforms, task, task-parallel-library

I was testing a piece of TPL code I wrote below. The two ManagedThreadId's display different numbers. The new task therefore, I am assuming, is running on a non UI thread.

My question is how is the task able to display a message and change a UI control? I am missing something. I thought I needed to get a reference to the UI's SynchronizationContext and use it to make UI changes from other threads.

```
//var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

Task testTask = new Task(() => {
        MessageBox.Show(
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
        lblTest.Text = "Test";
    });
testTask.Start();
```

**Addition:**

Download VS solution [here](http://www.4shared.com/get/mXspsT6i/testParallel2.html)

**Addition 2**

Can someone test the solution and mention if they get an exception or not?

Comment: Why the drive-by down vote?  Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work *unless* you use the [Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx) property to instruct the runtime not to validate that the calling thread matches the thread that the control was created on.

Your test code does crash for me in a brand new WinForms project (InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblTest' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on).  Is it possible that CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls(false) is being applied in your environment?

[image: Getting exception with your source code]

Comment: The code is in a click handler for a button. I don't get any errors. I see the two message boxes and the label's text changes. This is a Winform app in VS 2010 Windows 7 64 bit. The form has only the button and label. You can download the solution. See link above.

Comment: @Tony: I'm using VS 2010 SP1 on Windows 7 64 bit, created an empty WinForms project, added a button and a label, and put your code on the click handler for the button.  Can you reproduce with an empty project?

Comment: The download link above is based on an empty project. I tried it on two different machines and it worked.

Comment: @Tony: I'm getting the same exception running your source code (see image added to answer).

Comment: When I run without debugging, the label changes to 'Test'. When I run with debugger, the label doesn't change. In both cases I don't get any exceptions. Your behavior makes sense. I used two different computers (VS 2010 SP1 & Windows 7 64bit) and they behave the same way as I described. Can you make sense of why the different behaviors between you and me?

Comment: @Tony: Turns out after further reading, CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls defaults to true when debugging but false when running outside the debugger. A non-owning thread can actually access a control at any time (if that check is not in effect), but since controls are not guaranteed to be thread safe, it is to be avoided. See the following blog for details http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/05/12/416910.aspx

Comment: I enabled Common Language Runtime Exceptions and now I get the exception in the debugger. Thanks.